# How to get list of components in yahoo finance index using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

So im trying to get data from multiple stocks from yahoo finance and write it to excell.
The problem is at the moment i have to hardcode the stocks in question. and currently i would like to download the information from all 25 stocks in the C25 index (^OMXC25) or potentially other indexes. so therefore i would like to know how i can acces the components list and retrieve these and then download each of them. The current code i use to get each is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import datetime as dt

download_source = (r'C:\Users\SKlin\Downloads\OMXC25.xlsx')

start = dt.datetime(2010,1,1)
end = dt.datetime.today()

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(download_source, engine ='xlsxwriter')

#GN Store Nord
dfGN = pdr.get_data_yahoo('GN.CO',start,end)
dfGN.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='GN.CO')       

#Vestas Wind systems 
dfVestas = pdr.get_data_yahoo('VWS.CO',start,end)
dfVestas.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='VWS.CO')     

writer.save()
```

This saves the data just fint, but with 25 stocks it's doable, but seems tidious to do with index with 500 stocks.. Plz help.

Comment: Not familiar with Yahoo finance. Do you have a list of all stock symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use beautiful soup to scrape a list of the ticker names from wiki:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMX_Copenhagen_25

Then just iterate through them.

Comment: The problem here is that the ticker symbols is not the same on Wiki and yahoo.. :/

Comment: Then as gtomer says you will have to find it. Or just manual type it out once and then update when needed.

Comment: a quick google gets you the top 30. https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EOMXC25/components?p=%5EOMXC25. This wiki list would also be very easy to convert looking at this